# Battle Grid question

Tags: discussion

I would love to ask a question about the types of battle grids people use, as I think that it would make for a great resource on this site.  The only real problem is that it would be off-topic for being too broad unless it was made community wiki (which I'm perfectly ok with).

So my question is, could we get a question about the types of battle grids available without it being closed?

Questions that I think are in a similar vein:

- [What is important when choosing an rpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/423/what-is-important-when-choosing-an-rpg)
- [What tools are useful to organize a gm's notes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/267/what-tools-are-useful-to-organize-a-gms-campaign-notes)

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would prefer not to see a question that's just a list of all of the available types of grid. Yes, "What tools are useful to organize a GM's notes" managed to do fairly well in that context, but it's a really tough fit for the system. And most such questions do poorly.

"What is important when choosing a grid for you game/system/campaign" (pick one) could do fairly well on its own. I don't believe that it would have any need to be CW.

Compare and contrast questions ("what will happen if I replace grid system X with grid system Y?") can also work well, provided they are scoped to a specific situation, or perhaps of the form "when is grid system X preferable to grid system Y?"

Questions about a specific grid can also do well: "What are the advantages of grid system X?"

Finally, you can always go with "I am in situation X, what would a good grid system to use be?"

In general, if a topic MUST be CW to survive, it's a good sign that it will have problems. The current thinking (as I understand it) is that CW is for the rare question that gains a lot of community support, despite breaking the format.